# if $x^T*A*x=0$ can it be proven that det(A)=0

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, quadratic-forms

Sorry, for my lack of knowledge on the subject but can someone please tell me if the statement is true or not

```
   if $x^T*A*x=0$ can it be proven that, det(A)=0
```

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable with strictly non-negative real eigenvalues, or even has any canonical form with strictly non-negative entries, I suspect it is true. But that was not the question.

Comment: ( Also of course it is not true if x is allowed be 0 vector. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  It can't be shown that

$\det A = 0 \tag 1$

from

$x^TAx = 0; \tag 2$

take

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \tag 3$

and

$x = (1, 1)^T; \tag 3$

then (2) binds but

$\det A = -1; \tag 4$

or take

$A =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag 5$

and again choose $x$ as in (3); then again (2) holds but now

$\det A = 1. \tag 6$

Note that with $A$ as in (5), (2) binds for every $x$!